# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'name_category' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

I got, trouble in my project.. i don't know what should I be like! I hope other seniors and friends can help me with this problem.

This is my controller

```
  public function orderPacket($id){
$data_paket = DB::table('list_packet')->where('list_packet.id', $id)->join('d_list_packet', 'list_packet.id', '=', 'daftar_paket_detail.idPacket')->select('daftar_paket_detail.kode_packet as kode_packet')->get();
foreach ($data_packet as $packet) {
  $kode_packet = $paket->kode_packet;
  $data_kate = FD::where('kode_packet', $kode_packet)->value('nama_packet');
  $packet=  DFD::where([
    ['kode_packet', $kode_menu],
    ['status', '1'],
  ])->get();
  $data[] = [
    'name_category' => $data_kate,
    'data_packet' => $packet
  ];
}   
return View('user.order-packet',[
  'data' => $data
]);
```

}

Model data,

```
name_category = "Packet A",
data_packet = {
    [id = 121,
     kode_packet = PK-204,
     name_packet = Economical 1,
     price = 10.00
   ],
    [id = 111,
     kode_packet = PK-207,
     name_packet = Economical 2,
     price = 12.00
   ],
    [id = 145,
     kode_packet = PK-214,
     name_packet = Economical 3,
     price = 15.00
   ],
}

name_category = "Packet A",
data_packet = {
    [id = 132,
     kode_packet = PK-204,
     name_packet = Economical 1,
     price = 10.00
   ]
}
```

approxiately like this

And This is my blade

```
@foreach($data as $category)
  <div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <label for="">{{$category->name_category}}</label>
    <select class="form-control nasi mb-1" name="nasi" >
      <option value="">Pilih Nasi</option>
      @foreach($category->data_packet as $datas)
      <option value="{{$datas->kode_packet}}"> {{$datas->name_packet}} - {{number_format($datas->price,'0',',','.')}} </option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  @endforeach
```

[click for view controller screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV16e.png)
[click for view controller screeenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN58W.png)

Answer (score 0):

You created an array but your tried to get an object. I think it is your problem. 
try this code in your view

```
{{$category['name_category']}}
```